# How to build Qt applications using Team Foundation Server 2017

Tags: c++, qt, tfs

I am currently in the process of migrating a couple of legacy Qt5 projects to a new Team Foundation Server. All projects have been developed for Windows in Visual Studio using the Qt VS AddIn (and thus don't use .pro-files). I would love to use the TFS Build Agent to build these on other platforms (mainly linux).

I have previously done this on other projects using Jenkins and qmake, having platform-dependent settings in the .pro-file.

Is there an established workflow for building VS projects using Qt5 via a TFS Build Server on other platforms?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use TFS but, since TFS Build operates on Visual Studio solutions, it ought to be possible to use the "Linux development with C++" feature of VS2017. Just setup a Linux project in the VS solution and it should build like any other.

Comment: The thing is that I will need some kind of Qt support (moc, etc.) The VS Qt AddIn does this by converting a qmake project into a VS solution. Additionally projects should build in Windows and Linux.

Comment: For a cross-platform build you will mirror Windows and Linux projects in the same soultion, sharing the source code with perhaps the odd `#ifdef`. I suppose it comes down to how often you run the Qt addin and generate a VS solution; if it's every time you build then it's a non-starter, if it's a one-time only setup then it would be workable.

Comment: The problem I see with generating a VS solution from the qmake is that, similar to what you describe for code differences (using the preprocessor) one might need differentiation in the pre-build process as well (different locations for linked libraries, different tools that need to run before compilation). All this is trivial when using a build system like qmake or cmake...but I am worried if this translates to VS solutions...

Comment: I have VS soultions that build for Win32 and Linux simultaneously by having paired projects to target each platform. Mostly common code except for graphics. But these are hand crafted projects, I've no idea whether Qt could auto-generate them. Might be interesting to try.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you'd like to build Cross-Platform Code in Linux using TFS vNext build system. To build or deploy you'll need at least one agent. The [cross platform build agent](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent) is support on *Ubuntu*, *Red Hat*, and *CentOS*.

Detail steps please refer this tutorial-- [Deploy an agent on Linux](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-linux). Then simply create the build definition add build task, select the Linux build agent the same as build on windows. More detail step and build configuration you could take a look at this video tutorial-- [Building and Deploy Applications In Linux With TFS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4-0onY8gmU)

In your case, there is not corresponding  VS/Qt VS AddIn  in your Linux environment. You need to set up your Linux build agent local environment to build your qt5 application successfully, then it's not hard to build through tfs.

Another way is scripting the Linux build process to run over SSH or some other remote protocol, and driving this process from the Windows build agent.